NoSuchElementException even though locator used is working in Chrome
I am getting NoSuchElementException for an element and because of which my regression suite is failing. I have used XPATH, CSS selector and when searched in Chrome using those locators, I am able to find the element.
Till now I have used:

Thread.sleep(<milliseconds>)
Implicit Wait
Explicit/Fluent Wait using .visibilityOf(WebElement) and .prescenceOfElementLocatedBy(locator)

Even I have used Absolute XPath but no success.
Please suggest what I can do to make it work.
I need to capture the text content of h1 tag and then apply switch case based on the value captured, to perform further function. But my scripts are failing in locating h1.headline locator, however I can easily locate it in Chrome manually.
Below is my code:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("h1.headline")));
    
    String BDName = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("h1.headline")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
    System.out.println(BDName);
    BDName = BDName.trim();
    switch (BDName) {
    case "Authenticate Your Identity": {
        this.fnesignForConsumerFlow(qry);
        break;
    }
    case "Welcome to eQuipt!": {
        try {
            String strSubTitle = this.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[@class='sub-headline']"))
                    .getAttribute("innerHTML");

            if (strSubTitle.contains("Let's Get Started by Creating Your Username and Password")) {
                webmaileSign.fnEQuiptSignUp(qry);
                this.fnesignForConsumerFlow(qry);
            } else {
                this.fnesignWithOTP(qry);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        break;
    }

Below is the DOM structure:

Have you checked for the presence of IFRAMES or shadow-root? We can help if you share the URL of the website or at least the HTML. Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Thank You @Shawn for the response. I have checked the IFrames & ShadowDOM. The element is in the main DOM. I can not share the URL because I am facing the issue in client website.

Edit your question and share your code and the HTML of the page in the form of text.

What you want to perform on element click, capture the element can you define it in the question. If any action you can try to use JavaScriptExecutor

I have edited the question stating what does I want to do.

You need to edit your question and add the relevant HTML and full text of the error message.
